# How can I not take bugs found in software I work on personally?

Tags: communication, unprofessional-behavior

For a while, I'm being reported of strange bugs that are related to my code but once I investigate, I find those could not be eventually bugs.

Example: some data is NULL in the database, but the only query I have written to write a row in that particular table would fail with a null input.

There is only one explanation: 1 of the X people with database credentials have set that value to null, and usually those null values are in places that are surely to cause problems visibly in my parts of the code.

I have been having such problems for 3 months. I cannot say "Hi, someone is sabotaging me". So how do I handle that in the most professional way to reduce damage to my image. While at same time, avoiding damages to my company?

I'm very bored investigating non-bugs and that hurts my productivity.

Comment: Have you talked to the person who is setting the values to NULL in the database to find out why? Have you updated your code to handle the null values? If not, why not?

Comment: Seth. No matter how safe application code is, no matter how many constraints you put in a table, there will always be a way to introduce bugs manipulating data db directly if the credentials are shared with the whole team. Im not asking how to prevent that. It is impossible preventing that. Im asking how to handle the situation in the best possibile way to reduce damage.

Comment: The best way is to communicate with people and find out what they are doing with your code so you can design it accordingly. If someone is inserting null values into the DB where you weren't expecting them, you should go find out why. It could be a requirement you missed.

Comment: Can you add a non-NULL constraint on the column to the database?  Either that's possible, or your code needs to handle NULLs.

Comment: Who reported the bugs? Did you talk to that person to try to understand what they were doing when they hit the bug? Saying "there is only one explanation" is a mistake. Almost all software is complex enough that there is always some other unanticipated case.

Comment: Add a unit test that fails when a NULL is inserted, so you have some credibility. Log all DB access so you can see the command that inserted it (or that it was a hard edit somehow). Then set a watchdog process on the DB to query for NULL in that field, and alert when it happens, preferably with something that runs every minute or so. Adapt this to whatever the most recent non-bug is. Make sure the alert is visible to everyone in dev.

Comment: I'm on your side but up to a point. Sometimes it's really not your fault that users break the software. You cannot protect it from any invalid input possible, especially if the application is young (and you just don't have the time to implement all the guards). A good solution to this is to constrain the valid input and communicate it to the user and also tell the user what they must not do or otherwise they may or will break the application. [..]

Comment: [..] If you know where it's not allowed to enter NULLs and there is simply not enough time to properly handle it or because it's currently too complex then just include it in the specification. If they see there might be a problem then you might even get additional time to fix that behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

> There is only one explanation: 1 of the X people with database credentials have set that value to null, and usually those null values are in places that are surely to cause problems visibly in my parts of the code.

That means you write really fragile code that's easy to break.

Treat this as a technical challenge and **start validating your inputs**.

> I'm very bored investigating non-bugs and that hurts my productivity.

But these *are* bugs - the code is clearly not working.  When the code encounters an unexpected NULL, it should do something - probably report a data corruption error to the user.

Chasing down bugs is as much a part of the job as writing new code.  In mature code, it's most of the job.  If you're fixing bugs, you're being productive.

By the way, the answer to your title question

> How can I not take bugs personally?

is to remember that it's not your code.  The code belongs to the company or to the development team.   [Who wrote what is not important](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/154733/64132) and shouldn't matter.

Comment: Input are always validated indeed. At application level. Theresa are always loro of constraints at db level. But

Comment: If someone decides to introduce a bug in a db there is not much I can do

Comment: @Exiltaran If your DB allows null values and your application is using the data in the DB as _input_, then you should handle those null values. If you don't want people putting null values in your DB then you should not make those columns nullable. If you can't, then you must be prepared for them.

Comment: You are perfectly right, but this is happened hundred times so far. While there are things I can prevent with constraints, some are not preventable (like swapping 2 id in 2 rows of a relation). And moving to NO-SQL will prevent a lot of Security checks to be gone preventing me to avoid data manipulations.

Comment: @Exiltaran You are saying this happens "hundreds of times" with things like swapping ids in two rows.  That does not sound like someone manually going into the database, that sounds like bugs.

Comment: It is someone going into the db. I even made backups before leaving work. And checked the Morning. In the Night, There were no http calls to the app, but testDb changed. Now, when there is a bug I always assume I can fix It because It was my mistake. But not these. It is a relatively simple piece of software compared to other stuff I worked on. I'm not here to convince anyone this is true. I can barely believe that myself, because I trusted Everyeye single person in my team. But I had 3 months to come to conclusion. What I Need is just to handle the situation at my best. I cannot change It.

Answer (score 4):

Any code should take into account of erroneous input. It's unclear from your question how someone is "sabotaging" you by entering null data in the database. Null rows are common database data and your code should never assume all input is valid. Someone entering invalid data into your code is not "sabotaging" it especially if they are expecting some sort of output from it.

Now someone on the outside might sabotage your application. They could surmise that if you are not validating input, then it is entirely possible they could access the database through your broken code. Now if that is found to be from your code, it's a sure bet you might not have a job depending on your level.

Comment: It was for cutting short. In short if only the application is allowed to access the db, there would be' no bug. Someone is editing db tables directly. Im not speaking of null values only of course. I need to handle my reaction mostly since as long as X people is allowed to access the db  there is small I can do to prevent damage ( note also that my tables are relative the onestamente with most constraints, due to the periodic data manipulations they underwent)

Comment: Application input is validated.

Comment: Anyway the question is about how to handle that professionally. I cannot prevent that.

Comment: I'm reminded of Professor Farnsworth's comment, "You changed the outcome by measuring it." In your comments, you keep stating that it is the other person's fault for breaking your code. That is incorrect. Invalid data should be expected until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Development and QA teams should be communicating with each other.  It sounds like in the past three months, the QA team at your organization has shifted their focus or added new test cases or conditions.  This should not have come as a surprise to members of the Dev staff, but it has surprised at least one developer (you).

A new test or development focus is definitely something to talk about with your manager.  In this case, I would recommend just asking your manager about this new pattern, for example, *"I noticed that in the past few months QA is reporting a lot of new bugs related to data validation issues that appear to be unlikely to come up in standard use.  How do you want me to prioritize these?"*  Don't assume this is a positive or negative change.  Just bring it up and listen to the answer.

As others have mentioned here, bug reports that point out issues caused by not validating inputs are generally considered valid.  Maybe your company has decided to strengthen their architecture in this area in anticipation of some software expansion that may lead to more potential for bad data in these fields, and they asked QA to focus on tests like this.  Or maybe there is some new member on the QA staff who has a thing for input validation.  Or maybe QA just has a some time in their cycle to look at less-common test cases right now, but they don't expect these to be prioritized over other types of issues.

It's impossible to guess, but the good thing is that we don't have to: an unexpected change in type or quantity of issues being reported is exactly the sort of thing to discuss with a manager in determining what your main development priorities should be.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating bugs is part of the job of developing software.  Later in projects it is sometimes the main part of the job.

You should always write your code so that NULL database values do not cause a crash.  Always validate reads from your database as you would with user input from a screen.

Does your database (assuming test here) have auditing turned on?  If so it would be a simple to task to determine who last updated a row/column.  If this is a production database the n your company has larger issues.

Answer (score 0):

These really belongs on some software development site...

If you have bugs reported, and you try to fix them, follow my patented two-step approach. Step 1: You accept that there is something wrong somewhere with your code. Step 2: You find out *what* is wrong and fix it.

You are not following this simple recipe, so you are doomed to failure. As long as you look for reasons why this bug cannot happen, and for reasons why it is not your fault, or worse, that someone is sabotaging you, your mind isn't ready to accept the solution, that something was your fault, and all you need is to find that fault.